# How to get help on vim's `complete` variable, not vim's `complete' function?

Tags: vim, documentation

In vim, there is both a function and a variable called `complete`.

If you do `help complete`, you get the function's help.

How do you get the help for the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `:help complete` you get help on `complete()`, i.e. the function.

If you use `:help 'complete'`, you get help on the `'complete'` (or `'cpt'`) string.

This happens because of the way Vim's help system looks things up.  There is nothing called *just* `complete`, so the editor gives you  "the best matching thing" (see below), which happens to be `complete()`.

You should be able to manually press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after typing `:help complete` to have the help system auto-complete `:he complete()`.  Another press on <kbd>Tab</kbd> will replace that with `:he 'complete'`, then `:he 'completeopt'`, `:he complete_add()`, etc.

---

The Vim editor has this to say about what its help system does when it can't find an exact match for the thing you want help on:

> If there is no full match for the pattern, or there are several matches, the "best" match will be used. A sophisticated algorithm is used to decide which match is better than another one.  These items are considered in the computation:
>
> - A match with same case is much better than a match with different case.
> - A match that starts after a non-alphanumeric character is better than a match in the middle of a word.
> - A match at or near the beginning of the tag is better than a match further on.
> - The more alphanumeric characters match, the better.
> - The shorter the length of the match, the better.

(from [`:help {subject}`](https://vimhelp.org/helphelp.txt.html#%7Bsubject%7D))